# LWC ConnectedCallback Toast Notification Component Error When Roll up Record Count Field on Case Object is Not Null

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

I am trying to Load my LWC Toast component on a Case  basically showing toast notification using **connectedCallback** only when a Roll up Record Count Field on Case Object  is **not null** else i dont want LWC Toast component to even show up ,so here is the LWC written for that ,but when i open the Case record and try to open the tab i see error as

**P.S.** Here  **EST_Case_Type_Count__c** is Roll up summary count on Case object

[image]

JS

```
            import { LightningElement, api ,wire} from 'lwc';
            import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
            import {ShowToastEvent} from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

            const FIELDS = [
                'Case.EST_Case_Type_Count__c',

            ];

            export default class ERTCaseTypeInformation extends LightningElement {
              

                @api recordId;
                @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS })
                wiredErtCaseCounts;

               
                connectedCallback() {
                    

                    if(wiredErtCaseCounts !== null ){

                        var isFirstView = localStorage.getItem('isFirstView') || '';

                    

                        if (isFirstView !== 'Yes') {
                        var toast = new ShowToastEvent({
                                 'title': 'Case Type Level 1, level 2 and level 3 fields ',
                                 'message': 'must be selected before saving',
                                 variant: 'success',
                             });
                             this.dispatchEvent(toast);
                       }
                
                        localStorage.clear(); 
                       localStorage.setItem('isFirstView', 'Yes');
                       localStorage.removeItem('isFirstView');
                    }


                    }
                



            }
```

html

```
            <template>
                <lightning-record-view-form record-id={recordId} object-api-name="Case">

                    <div class = "slds-grid">
                        <lightning-output-field field-name="EST_Case_Type_Count__c"></lightning-output-field>
                    </div>

                </lightning-record-view-form>

                </template>
```

Meta XML

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
                <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
                <isExposed>true</isExposed>
              <masterLabel>EST CaseType Levels Info Component</masterLabel>
              <description>EST CaseType Levels Info Component.</description>
              <targets>
                  <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
                  <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
                  <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
              </targets>
            </LightningComponentBundle>
```

Please let me know what needs to be corrected in the code to get rid off this **Component Error**

Regards

Fiona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you refer a property of a lightning web component, you use **this**. You have written:-

```
connectedCallback() {
   if(wiredErtCaseCounts !== null ){ 
     // other code goes here
   }
}
```

instead you shoud writeas below, it will make sure you are referring to right property. Also to check if property is having some value, just write the property inside if condition:-

```
connectedCallback() {
   if(this.wiredErtCaseCounts){ 
     // other code goes here
   }
}
```